# Why are there no buttons appearing in my Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a Beginner at coding and I am having a Pretty Basic Problem.
I tried to do an application after a Video on Youtube.
At first there was no button with the text "Hello World" like it was in the Video.
Then I tried to drag an Drop a Button on the layout area, but Nothing happened.
Does somebody know how to fix this ?

Thanks a lot.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please add the content of your xml file. Thanks.

Comment: Can you click on the "Text" tab next to the "Design" tab and paste that xml here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> please follow these steps

```
1- Go to your res folder and inside res folder.
2-Go to values.
3-Go to style.xml
4-change  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: please let me know if it is useful to you

Comment: thanks a lot ! It worked !
Can you explain what was wrong an what you did to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to that red exclamation and see the error, as you might be having a render issue.